# ical4j open Calendar from external URL

Tags: java, ical4j

I would like to open a .ical - File (e.g. Google calendar).. I´m currently try this but it doesn´t work. I got the following execption:

> net.fortuna.ical4j.data.ParserException: Error at line 138:[CREATED] Unparseable date: "00001229T000000Z"

So it seems there is something wrong with the parsing from the date..

Here my code:

```
    public Calendar readCalenderFromUrl(CalendarExtern calendarExtern)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException, ParserException {

    // Create a TimeZone
    System.setProperty("net.fortuna.ical4j.timezone.cache.impl", MapTimeZoneCache.class.getName());

    URL url = new URL(calendarExtern.getUrlExtern());
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "ISO-8859-15");
    CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
    Calendar thisCalendar = builder.build(r);

    return thisCalendar;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Syntactically the date may be valid, but probably the fact the year component is `0000` might be causing the error

Comment: Thank you but how can I change that? Why spould it be 0000 ? It´s coming from Google Calendar...?